# OpenLayers WFS service with GML

Tags: openlayers, wfs, gml

I'm trying to get features from WFS service, this service using stored queries. I've managed to retrieve data both with axios and XMLHttpRequest. But the problem in the reading features and showing them on my layer.

My sample code:

```
let vector; 

let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    var format = new GML3();
    var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    vector = new Vector({
        source: new VectorSource({
            format: format
        })
    });



    for (var i = 1; i < xmlDoc.children[0].children.length; i++) {

        console.log('xmlDoc.children[0].children[i] >>> ', xmlDoc.children[0].children[i]);
        let features = format.readFeatures(xmlDoc.children[0].children[i]);

        console.log('features >>> ', features);
        // features.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
        vector.getSource().addFeature(features);
    }

    map.addLayer(vector);
    // map.getView().fit(vector.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize())
};

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);

// trigger the GET request
xmlhttp.send();
```

So when i run this code, console tells that "Uncaught TypeError: feature.getId is not a function". I'm using OpenLayers 4. Could anyone explain what happening ? As i understood there is a class Feature , which has set and get id's methods. Moreover is it possible to convert my GML response into the geoJson , maybe it will be easier to work with ?

Comment: To answer your second question, your WFS may offer GeoJSON as an output format, so possibly no reason to do a conversion.

Comment: What WFS version are you using and what version GML is returned? Is it simple feature WFS?

Comment: No, it supports only 
<ows:Operation name="GetFeature">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>text/xml; version=3.2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/gml+xml; subtype=gml/3.2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/gml+xml; version=3.2</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>

Comment: WFS version = 2.0.0 because 
<ows:Parameter name="version">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>2.0.0</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Parameter

Comment: I dont know how to identify simple or not simple WFS , i really  dont know what to do with this responses, i tried a lot of ways , and cant figure out how to use it, or transform it into JSON

Comment: Not sure that GML 3.2 is supported by OL 3+

Comment: I also was thinking about it because docs tells  "Currently only supports GML 3.1.1 Simple Features profile."

Comment: Does it mean that some namespaces shall not be seen ?